# Div Not Showing Up for Unknown Reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a simple width, height, background color, and margin:0 auto yet it won't show up and I can't figure out why. In Dreamweaver, it actually shows up just fine, but not in browsers. This is becoming problematic because I need it to center other content (the only reason I gave it a colored background and didn't put anything inside was to troubleshoot). The page with the problem is [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/nationals_website/web_design.html). My code is below

HTML

```
<div id="7steps"></div>
```

CSS

```
#7steps {
width:1100px;
margin:0 auto;
height:1000px;
background-color:#960;
}
```

It has to be some sort of conflicting code that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the div has no content? Are you sure it is not actually being placed within the DOM?

Comment: When I put content inside it (i.e. the divs with the horizontal line and the understand a website, learn to code) it didn't do anything. Inspecting the element showed the div put no width or height. It was almost as if my CSS somehow didn't apply. And yet in Dreamweaver (not in live view) it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ID can't start with a number, and height and width doesn't really apply without a position

```
<div id="steps7"></div>
```

and

```
#steps7 {
  width:1100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:#960;
  position: relative;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gk7Cq/)